# HTML anchor href download sees network failure but same line works sans download and pasted in address bar

Tags: html, google-chrome-extension, anchor

Until the lastest disaster from the Chromium team the following worked perfectly

```
<td valign="top">
   <a href="https://chrysalis-systems.net/shared/tmp/dfmapbCNAPQ1.dot" download="">
      <button type="button" title="download graph specification (graphViz:dot)">
         <img src="/dflibg/sdk/images/downloadA32.png">
         </button>
      </a>
   </td>
<td valign="top">
   <a href="https://chrysalis-systems.net/shared/tmp/dfmapbCNAPQ1.png" print="" target="_blank">
      <button type="button" title="print or save graph">
         <img src="/dflibg/sdk/images/printerC.png">
         </button>
      </a>
   </td>
```

Now, however,

1. although the href for opening the image in a new blank window works fine,
2. the href for downloading the dot-spec text file does not work any longer,

   the infamous "Failed Network Error" [Never used to happen in many years!!!!!]
   BUT
3. works if pasted into an address bar.

The files are there; same ownership; same permissions:

[root@amauris4 logs]# ls -lt $DOCUMENT_ROOT/shared/tmp/dfmapbCNAPQ1*
-rw-r--r--. 1 apache apache  478 Mar  4 20:04 /mnt/sr/web/html/shared/tmp/dfmapbCNAPQ1.map
-rw-r--r--. 1 apache apache 6792 Mar  4 20:04 /mnt/sr/_web/html/shared/tmp/dfmapbCNAPQ1.png
-rw-r--r--. 1 apache apache  843 Mar  4 20:04 /mnt/sr/_web/html/shared/tmp/dfmapbCNAPQ1.dot

Hence it is not a problem with the 'referrer' as some have postulated... Same referrer in 1 and 2.

The server log ONLY shows the image request...

192.168.2.254 - - [04/Mar/2023:20:42:14 -0500] "HEAD /shared/tmp/dfmapbCNAPQ1.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
192.168.2.254 - - [04/Mar/2023:20:42:14 -0500] "GET /shared/tmp/dfmapbCNAPQ1.png HTTP/1.1" 200 6792

It's as if the browser never even tried.  Firewall? Really? [Disabled, same result.] Same url path.

No error messages in the console log of dev tools for the requesting process.

So, I'm at a loss.
The 'host' of the above html is a foreground page of an extension.
The 'host' can access the image url shown above (the .png file)  with <img src='...>
without any problem. The print button (open the image) button works fine.  Its just the download that no longer (I repeat no longer) works.
Attached is a snippet of the screen shot show that you can visualize what I'm referencing.
[image: this is the rendered html]

And I am now getting this result from both google chrome and edge- firefox is kinda like 'give up all hope ye who enter here' so I don't have an example (anymore)

Comment: ps ignore the  .map file path (its not part of the issue - just a stub fo a clickable dataflow graph)

Answer (score 0):

The answer appears to be in two parts - both particular to running in an extension environment versus 'in the wild'.

1. Once upon a time, it was permissible for an 'insecure' page to request a 'secure' resource - just not the other way around. This recently changed.
   Now, the application or the content script in the application tab must tell the extension daemon/foreground/whatever the protocol to use on behalf of the page it is operating on behalf. [Iff the extension supports both http and https pages.]
2. Within the extension environment ONLY, the environment can chose to ignore an https request and munge it into an http request - claim that it is now insecure (even though accessible) and then refuse the download. Why,[as per Shakespeare in Love], "it's a mystery".  However, the fix -part 2 - was to also prepend the www. to the domain name.  Again, outside of the extension context - no problem - inside, fubar.